# PhP validation not exiting properly

Tags: php, html

i am trying to sort out my validation, below is my code, i have tried loads of things including turning it into an `if else` structure, however whatever i test with it always returns the error for no email, and i am not sure why. I have even tried removing the `exit;` from the first if, but still just shows no email.

```php
if(!$reg_username){

     $reg_error = "You have not entered a Username.";
      $_SESSION['error'] = $reg_error;
      header("Location: register.php");
      exit;
 }

 if (!$reg_email){

     $reg_error = "You have not entered an Email.";
      $_SESSION['error'] = $reg_error;
      header("Location: register.php");
      exit;

 }
 if (!$reg_password){

     $reg_error = "You have not entered a Password.";
      $_SESSION['error'] = $reg_error;
      header("Location: register.php");
      exit;
 }
 if (!$reg_password_1){

     $reg_error = "You have not entered your Verification Password.";
      $_SESSION['error'] = $reg_error;
      header("Location: register.php");
      exit;
 }
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks

EDIT: Here is the rest of the code

```
$reg_username = $_POST['reg_username'];
     $reg_email = $_POST['reg_email'];
     $reg_password = $_POST['reg_password'];
     $reg_password_1 = $_POST['reg_password_1'];
     $reg_dob_day = $_POST['reg_dob_day'];
     $reg_dob_month = $_POST['reg_dob_month'];
     $reg_dob_year = $_POST['reg_dob_year'];


     include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";
     $reg_username_length = "";
     $reg_password_length = "";
     $reg_dob_day_length = "";
     $reg_dob_year_length = "";


     $reg_email = stripslashes($reg_email); 
     $reg_password = stripslashes($reg_password); 
     $reg_password_1 = stripslashes($reg_password_1); 
     $reg_dob_day = stripslashes($reg_dob_day); 
     $reg_dob_month = stripslashes($reg_dob_month); 
     $reg_dob_year = stripslashes($reg_dob_year); 

     $reg_email = strip_tags($email);
     $reg_password = strip_tags($password);
     $reg_password_1 = strip_tags($reg_password_1);
     $reg_dob_day = strip_tags($reg_dob_day); 
     $reg_dob_month = strip_tags($reg_dob_month); 
     $reg_dob_year = strip_tags($reg_dob_year);



     $reg_username = mysql_real_escape_string($reg_username);
     $reg_email = mysql_real_escape_string($reg_email);
     $reg_password = mysql_real_escape_string($reg_password);
     $reg_password_1 = mysql_real_escape_string($reg_password_1);
     $reg_dob_day = mysql_real_escape_string($reg_dob_day);
     $reg_dob_month = mysql_real_escape_string($reg_dob_month);
     $reg_dob_year = mysql_real_escape_string($reg_dob_year);


     if(!$reg_username){

         $reg_error = "You have not entered a Username.";
          $_SESSION['error'] = $reg_error;
          header("Location: register.php");
          exit;
     }

     if (!$reg_email){

         $reg_error = "You have not entered an Email.";
          $_SESSION['error'] = $reg_error;
          header("Location: register.php");
          exit;
     }
     if (!$reg_password){

         $reg_error = "You have not entered a Password.";
          $_SESSION['error'] = $reg_error;
          header("Location: register.php");
          exit;
     }
     if (!$reg_password_1){

         $reg_error = "You have not entered your Verification Password.";
          $_SESSION['error'] = $reg_error;
          header("Location: register.php");
          exit;
     }
     if ($reg_password != $reg_password_1){

         $reg_error = "Your Verification Passwords do no match.";
          $_SESSION['error'] = $reg_error;
          header("Location: register.php");
          exit;
     }
```

Comment: Try replacing `exit;` with `die();`

Comment: `var_dump($reg_email);` - it will have some falsy value. You then can ask the next question like *"Why is my `$reg_email` always falsy?"*

Comment: ok, i tried the var_dump and it shows nothing, so i var_dumped at the very start of the script and it shows the correct email, but the only code inbetween is performing a (stripslash, strip_tags and a mysql_real_escape_string), would this cause the email variable to become nothing?

Comment: @Arken Post the rest of the code. That can't cause the variable to lose value.

Comment: @praveen: and this would change this... how? both terminate the script

Comment: Please show us your form and whole code of the above page.

Comment: try to check $reg_email variable value as echo $reg_email .....then try to change it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your following line:

```
$reg_email = strip_tags($email);
```

should be like this:

```
$reg_email = strip_tags($reg_email);
```

It seems you just mistype the variable name.